# Put version to my java application - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, version

Is there any way that i can give a version number to my application in netbeans.And then access that version number inside my code.

Something similar to the Assembly number that we use in .Net.Is there anything like that in java or in netbeans...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define an `Implementation-Version` in the manifest of the Jar at build time.  It is common to use some form of the date as the version number.  E.G. `14.07.28`

The value can be retrieved in code using..

```
String version = this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

---

```xml
<tstamp>
    <format property="now" pattern="yy.MM.dd"/>
</tstamp>
...
<jar
    destfile="build/dist/lib/${jar.name}"
    update='true'
    index='true' >
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Created-By" value="${vendor}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${application.title}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${vendor}"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor-Id" value="org.pscode"/>
        <!-- This next property is retrieved in code above. -->
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${now}"/>
    </manifest>
    <fileset dir="build/share">
        <include name="${package.name}/*.class" />
        <include name="${package.name}/*.png" />
    </fileset>
</jar>
```

This comes from a build file for a project I have open at the moment.  The relevant attribute is the last one in the manifest section.

Comment: Any idea on how to set this using netbeans?

Comment: I don't use netbeans, but I know netbeans understands Ant build files, and doing it from a build file is relatively trivial.  I will adjust the answer to give a small snippet of Ant example.

Answer (score 2):

In my JavaFX app created in Netbeans, I can set the build version (Implementation version) in the Project Properties window shown here:
[image: Screenshot of Netbeans Project Properties]

This number is then used everywhere, for example it is automatically inserted into the filename of the installer. It is also the number retrieved by `this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();` mentioned by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about .NET assembly numbers, but if you're creating a web application you can certainly put a version number into the manifest of your WAR file.

Any Java package can have a build info text file added to it so you can tell these things.

Your version number could be a build number from Ant, a version number from Subversion, or a combination of the two.

Comment: How can i get the Build number? do i have to put a build number myself into a text file or is it generated?